# New context menu entry in notepad++

Tags: notepad++

Everything I do in my work I write down in Notepad++.
I have a lot of links to other files, like this:

```
TITLE 1
Did this and that.
c:\abc\def\test4.txt

TITLE 2
Did this and that.
c:\aaa\bbb\ccc\test5.txt
```

When I mouse-click the link 3 times, the whole link is selected.

It would help a lot to now have a line in my Notepad++ context menu:
Open selected in Notepad++.

How can I achieve this?
Thanks alot for any hints

Comment: Use MSWord to write down ;)

Comment: See http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Context_Menu

Comment: Look at the "Run" menu which has entries for `Launch in Firefox` or `...IE` etc.